# Как экспортировать скрипт python, чтобы он работал на ms-dos?

Tags: python-3.x

Пробовал с помощью pyinstaller и в dos была ошибка this program cannot be run in dos mode. Эта программа без графического интерфейса с модулями os и time.

Comment: Скачать [интерпретатор Python для DOS](http://www.caddit.net/pythond/) и запускать с помощью него.

Comment: Модуль os не работает. Возможно в dos его нет.